# Fluentbit with mycat multiline parsing

Tags: parsing, elasticsearch, fluentd, fluent-bit

I want make a log management system through EFK. I'm trying for days now to get my multiline mycat log parser to work with fluent-bit.

My fluentbit configuration:

```
parsers.conf:
    [PARSER]
      Name        mycat_error_log_parser_head
      Format      regex
      Regex       ^(?<time>(\d)+(-\d+)+(\S)+\W(\S)+)(\s+)(?<action>\S+)(\s+)(?<on>\S+)
      Time_Key    time
      Time_Format %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%L
      Time_Keep   On

    [PARSER]
      Name        mycat_error_log_parser
      Format      regex
      Regex       ^(?<time>(\d)+(-\d+)+(\S)+\W(\S)+)(\s+)(?<action>\S+)(\s+)(?<on>\S+)(\s+)(?<content>(.|\s)*)$
      Time_Key    time
      Time_Format %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%L
      Time_Keep   On

fluent-bit.conf
    [INPUT]
        Name tail
        tag mycat
        path /var/log/mycat.log
        Multiline On
        Parser_Firstline mycat_error_log_parser_head
        Parser mycat_error_log_parser
        Path_Key file
```

and the mycat.log looks like this:

```
mycat.log
2018-08-02 09:59:41.205  INFO [$_NIOConnector] (io.mycat.backend.datasource.PhysicalDatasource.getConnection(PhysicalDatasource.java:529)) - no ilde connection in pool,create new connection for hostS1 of schema mysql
2018-08-02 09:59:53.939  INFO [Timer0] (io.mycat.backend.datasource.PhysicalDatasource.getConnection(PhysicalDatasource.java:529)) - no ilde connection in pool,create new connection for hostS1 of schema mysql
2018-08-02 10:00:01.173 ERROR [$_NIOConnector] (io.mycat.net.NIOConnector.finishConnect(NIOConnector.java:155)) - error:
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method) ~[?:1.7.0_111]
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:744) ~[?:1.7.0_111]
    at io.mycat.net.NIOConnector.finishConnect(NIOConnector.java:165) ~[Mycat-server-1.6.5-release.jar:?]
    at io.mycat.net.NIOConnector.finishConnect(NIOConnector.java:143) ~[Mycat-server-1.6.5-release.jar:?]
    at io.mycat.net.NIOConnector.run(NIOConnector.java:98) ~[Mycat-server-1.6.5-release.jar:?]
2018-08-02 10:00:01.173  INFO [$_NIOConnector] (io.mycat.net.AbstractConnection.close(AbstractConnection.java:514)) - close connection,reason:java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out ,MySQLConnection [id=0, lastTime=1533175073937, user=root, schema=mysql, old shema=mysql, borrowed=false, fromSlaveDB=true, threadId=0, charset=utf8, txIsolation=3, autocommit=true, attachment=null, respHandler=null, host=parse1, port=3306, statusSync=null, writeQueue=0, modifiedSQLExecuted=false]
2018-08-02 10:00:01.173  INFO [$_NIOConnector] (io.mycat.sqlengine.SQLJob.connectionError(SQLJob.java:117)) - can't get connection for sql :select user()
```

I think about i'm close now, but no luck so far.

In my kibana. I get follow result:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m61Dm.png)

My multi-line error log is missing. but i testing in rubular it normal parsing
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fho4O.png)

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Were you able to solve this ? I am stuck in the same place. Something to note is `Parser` in `fluent-bit.conf` won't be used in `Multiline On` mode

Answer (score 2):

This configuration worked for your log file, Fluent Bit published 5 documents to elastic search with this configuration.

```
   parsers.conf
    [PARSER]
      Name        mycat_error_log_parser_head
      Format      regex
      Regex       ^(?<time>(\d)+(-\d+)+(\S)+\W(\S)+)(\s+)(?<action>\S+)(\s+)(?<on>\S+)(\s+)(?<content>.*)
      Time_Key    time
      Time_Format %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%L
      Time_Keep On

    [PARSER]
      Name        mycat_error_log_parser
      Format      regex
      Regex       (?m-ix)^(?<time>(\d)+(-\d+)+(\S)+\W(\S)+)(\s+)(?<action>\S+)(\s+)(?<on>\S+)(\s+)(?<content>.*)
      Time_Key    time
      Time_Format %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%L
      Time_Keep On


  fluent-bit.conf
   [INPUT]
      Name tail
      tag mycat
      path /var/log/mycat.log
      Multiline On
      Parser_Firstline mycat_error_log_parser_head
      Parser_1 mycat_error_log_parser
      Path_Key file
```

Two changes done to the configuration from the question - Regex config has been changed in [PARSER] sections and Parser changed to Parser_1 in [INPUT] section.

I had faced similar problem with multiline parsing, my observation is that Parser_Firstline should cover the entire first line in the multiline message and Parser_1 .. Parser_N should cover the entire structure of multiline message.

Fluent Bit documentation on multiline configuration: https://fluentbit.io/documentation/0.12/input/tail.html

Answer (score 1):

Please change `Parser` to `Parser_1`.

`Parser_Firstline` must be the regex matching all except the multiline exceptions
and `Parser_1` must be the regex matching all including multiline exceptions.